# derivation of binary mass function for eccentric orbit

Tags: eccentric-orbit, radial-velocity

When investigating methods to detect exoplanets, I learned about binary mass function(BMF) which could be applied to obtain radial velocity and the mass. I've derived BMF for a circular orbit, but I get wrong answer when it comes to an eccentric orbit.

$$
\frac{M_2^3}{M_{tot}^2}=\frac{4\pi^2}{G P^2}a_1^3 \\
$$
from:
$$
-\frac{GM_1M_2}{a(1-e)}+ \frac{1}{2}M_1v_1^2 + \frac{1}{2}M_2v_2^2
=-\frac{GM_1M_2}{a(1+e)}+ \frac{1}{2}M_1v_1^{{'2}} + \frac{1}{2}M_2v_2^{'2} \\
M_1v_1a_1(1-e)=M_1v_1^{'}a_1(1+e)\\
M_2v_2a_2(1-e)=M_2v_2^{'}a_2(1+e)\\
M_1v_1=M_2v_2\\
a = a_1\frac{M_{tot}}{M_2}
$$
I got:
$$
a_1=\frac{1+e}{1-e}\frac{GM_2^3}{M_{tot}^2 v_1^2}
$$
so:
$$
\frac{M_2^3}{M_{tot}^2}=\frac{Pv_1^3}{2\pi G}(\frac{1-e}{1+e})^{3/2}=\frac{PK^3}{2\pi G \sin^3 i}(\frac{1-e}{1+e})^{3/2}
$$
However, result from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_mass_function) is:
$$
f = \frac{M_2^3 \sin^3 i}{M_{tot}^2} = \frac{P  K^3}{2\pi  G}(1-e^2)^{3/2}
$$

I'm wondering what's wrong with my calculation...

Comment: Hello and welcome to Astronomy SE. What exactly is your question here?

Comment: @PierrePaquette the question has been nicely updated; I think it was just accidentally posted before it was finished.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to find detailed derivation online after my fail. Finally I found it in **The Exoplanet Handbook** by *Michael Perryman*:

Actrually K, or the so called **radial velocity semi-amplitude**, is not the peak radial velocity (which I understand before) but **some kind of amplitude of the fluctuation of the radial velocity**. And it must be considered in 3D space.
let z = star position alone the line of sight = $r(t) \sin(\omega + \theta)\sin i$
[image: sketch]

then radial velocity $v_r = \dot{z} = \sin{i}[\dot{r}\sin(\omega + \theta)+r \dot{\theta}\cos(\omega+\theta)]$.
on the other hand, we have:
$$
r = \frac{a_1(1-e^2)}{1+e\cos{\theta}} \\
\cos{\theta} = \frac{\cos{E}-e}{1-e\cos{E}} \\
E - e\sin{E} = \frac{2\pi}{P}t
$$
where $E=E(t)$ is the so called **eccentric anomaly**.
After lengthy calculation, we get:
$$
v_r(t) = \frac{2\pi a_1}{P}\frac{\sin{i}}{\sqrt{1-e^2}}[e\cos{\omega} + \cos(\omega + \theta(t))]
$$
and here appears K (amplitude):
$$ K = \frac{2\pi a_1}{P}\frac{\sin{i}}{\sqrt{1-e^2}}$$
use this to substitute $a_1$ in Kepler's Third Law:
$$
\frac{M_2^3}{M^2_{tot}}=\frac{4π^2}{GP^2}a_1^3
$$
at last there is:
$$
\frac{M_2^3 \sin^3 i}{M_{tot}^2}=\frac{PK^3}{2\pi G}(1-e^2)^{3/2}
$$